# Django - diagnose issue with Class and view

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to send a variable to html using Django forms and templates.

This is my code...

```
class AdminView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'admin.html'

def admin(self, request):
    template = 'admin.html'
    data = Quiz.objects.all()
    form = AdminForm(request.POST)
    context = {"form": form}
    context['admin'] = data
    # return render(request, template, context)
    return render_to_response(context)
```

What is wrong with this code? How come it the variable doesn't appear on the website.

The line context = {"form", form} has been highlighed in my IDE as and error.

Error: This dictionary creation could be rewritten as a dictionary literal.

How does this look?

```
class AdminView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'admin.html'

def post(self, request):
    template = 'admin.html'
    data = Quiz.objects.all()
    form = AdminForm(request.POST)
    context = {"form": form}
    context['admin'] = data
    return render(request, template, context)
```

Unfortunately still doesn't work?

This is the html code...

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated%}
    {% if request.user.username  == "teacher"  %}
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            {% load staticfiles %}
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Admin</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'style.css' %}" />
        </head>
        <body>
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}

        Admin Test

        {{ admin }}



        </body>
        </html>
    {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is simply a style issue and has nothing to do with the actual problem.

There a couple of real problems with your code. The first is that you can't just define an arbitrary method like `admin` and expect it to be called. You need to define either `get` or `post` here.

The second is that `render_to_response` needs to be given the template name. Your commented-out version using `render` was correct.

Comment: Okay, I've added a bit to the question. How does that look? It doesn't seem to work still.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the identation, If you want to send extra context to the template you can use `get_context_data()` method, like this:

```
class AdminView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'admin.html'

    '''
    This is for a GET request
    '''
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(AdminView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['admin'] = Quiz.objects.all()
        context['form'] = AdminForm()
        return context

    '''
    This is for a POST request
    '''
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = AdminForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # do something if form data is valid
        else:
            # do something if form data is not valid
        return render(request, 'admin.html', context)
```

But if you want proccess a form, i suggest you use `FormView` instead of `TemplateView`

Comment: I think you've miss-understood my aims, I am trying to display the data from the database onto the website.